# bpy - detect modified mesh data (vertices, edges, loops, or polygons) for caching

Tags: python, mesh, cache

say I have some deterministic expensive function `calc_foo`, that operates on a bpy.objects.Mesh.

How can I detect if a given bpy.objects.Mesh object is identical-to (unmodified-from) a previously processed mesh object.

Comment: I've never used it, but you could try `unit_test_compare` See 2nd answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28793/how-to-tell-whether-object-is-a-duplicate

Comment: @Psyonic thanks for a recommendation, `unit_test_compare` appears to be quite sophisticated, i think it crawls a huge variety of mesh properties (see https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/3022a805caaec98aa83f6a982eda4cba19659bc8/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/mesh.cc#L766-L807) however, it primarily asserts equality, and I need to determine exactly what is different so these differences can be used as primary keys. Its very interesting to look at blender function, i thought it was much shallower than it is before I found it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is reliable, but for now i'm leveraging python's `hash()` of strings and tuples to impose an order-based hash of a mesh

```
def MESH_PROP_cachekey_get(self):
    return str(hash((
        bl_info['name'],
        bl_info['version'],
        tuple(tuple(i.co) for i in self.vertices),
        tuple((i.vertices[0], i.vertices[1]) for i in self.edges),
        tuple((i.vertex_index, i.edge_index) for i in self.loops),
        tuple(tuple(i.loop_indices) for i in self.polygons),
    )))

def register():
    bpy.types.Mesh.cachekey = bpy.props.StringProperty(get=MESH_PROP_cachekey_get)
```

must be str, because the int is too large for a blender Int

this seems to be a reasonable way to hash a mesh to me,
I can then journal this in bpy

```py
if obj.data.cachekey != obj.get('last_cachekey', None):
    print('mesh is dirty: %s' % obj)
obj['last_cachekey'] = obj.data.cachekey
```

or

```
db = dict()
if obj.get('last_cachekey', None) is not None and obj.data.cachekey not in db:
    print('mesh not indexed: %s' % obj)
```

also, r.i.p to performance doing integer comparisons as strings